# Search pivot table Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

I have 3 tables

```
students
- id
- name

classes
- id
- name

student_class
- id
- student_id
- class_id
- score
```

I want to return a list of the students that belong to **class_id = 100**

```
$students = \Student::where(['class_id' => 100])->get();
```

this is my Student Class

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Student extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'students';

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $student = new Student;
        $student->save();
    }  
}
```

the error I´m getting is:

```
<strong>Message:</strong> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'class_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `students` where (`class_id` = 100))
```

**update:** I can do

```
$students = \Class::find(100)->with(['students'])->get();
```

and it will return all the students as a child of classes but I don´t need that.
I need the data from students and the pivot table (student_class) in particular de score column.

thank you for your help

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : in both of your model relation add

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Class')->withPivot('score');
```

now you can do this inside your loop

```
foreach ($student->classes as $class) {
    echo $class->pivot->score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your student model as

```
public function classes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Class::class, 'student_class', 'student_id', 'class_id');
}
```

//query

```
Student::whereHas('classes', function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 100);
})->get();
```